# Как сортировать второй столбец на основе значений первого столбца?

Tags: sql, oracle

Пытаюсь извлечь данные из таблицы, но мне нужно, чтобы они были отсортированы специфическим образом, и не уверен, возможно ли это в SQL.

Что мне нужно, извлечь все строки, но упорядочить их так, чтобы там, где столбец 3 `null`, то они были бы упорядочены первыми. Затем, все строки, которые не являются нулевыми в столбце 3, будут показаны ПОСЛЕ строки, которая имеет их значение в столбце 1.

Что есть:

```
+------+-------+------+
| Col1 | Col2  | Col3 |
+------+-------+------+
|    1 | text  |      |
|    2 | text  |    1 |
|    3 | text  |    1 |
|    8 | text  |   10 |
|    9 | text  |   10 |
|   10 | text  |      |
+------+-------+------+
```

Что хотелось бы получить:

```
+------+-------+------+
| Col1 | Col2  | Col3 |
+------+-------+------+
|    1 | text  |      |
|    2 | text  |    1 |
|    3 | text  |    1 |
|   10 | text  |      |
|    8 | text  |   10 |
|    9 | text  |   10 |
+------+-------+------+
```

---

Что уже пробовал.

Первое, что попробовал:

```
ORDER BY coalesce(Col3, Col1)
```

Результат почти близкий к ожидаемому, но значение `Col1=10` должно быть перед значением `Col3=10`:

```
+------+-------+------+
| Col1 | Col2  | Col3 |
+------+-------+------+
|    1 | text  |      |
|    2 | text  |    1 |
|    3 | text  |    1 |
|    8 | text  |   10 |
|    9 | text  |   10 |
|   10 | text  |      |
+------+-------+------+
```

Я также пытался создать новую колонку, где если Col3 равен `null`, то Col4 - `true`, а `false`-  в противном случае. Но по сути, это то же самое, что и с coalesce выше.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Ordering second column based on the first column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65429356) от участника [@stackiee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13001752/stackiee)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65429356

Answer (score 3):

Достаточно сортировать по признаку - `nulls` в первую очередь:

```
select *
from t
order by coalesce (col3, col1), col3 nulls first, col1
/

      COL1 COL2       COL3
---------- ---- ----------
         1 text           
         2 text          1
         3 text          1
        10 text           
         8 text         10
         9 text         10
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65429381) от участника [@Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)</sub>